# Summarizing count data as proportion in a data.frame

Tags: r, summary

```
dummy <- data.frame(Q1 = c(0, 1, 0, 1),
                    Q2 = c(1, 1, 0, 1),
                    Q3 = c(0, 1, 1, 0))
df_dummy <- data.frame(Question = c("Q1", "Q2", "Q3"),
                       X1 = c(2/4, 3/4, 2/4),
                       X0 = c(2/4, 1/4, 2/4))

> dummy
  Q1 Q2 Q3
1  0  1  0
2  1  1  1
3  0  0  1
4  1  1  0

> df_dummy
  Question   X1   X0
1       Q1 0.50 0.50
2       Q2 0.75 0.25
3       Q3 0.50 0.50
```

I have some data (`dummy`) where I have binary responses to Q1, Q2, and Q3. I want to summarize my data in the format as shown in `df_dummy`, where for each question, column `X1` tells me the proportion of people that answered 1 to Q1, and column `X0` tells me the proportion of people that answered 0 to Q0. I tried `prop.table` but that didn't return the desired result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another way is counting the proportion of `1s` and then deducing from that the proportion of `0s`:

```
X1 <- colSums(dummy==1)/nrow(dummy)
df_dummy <- data.frame(X1, X0=1-X1)
df_dummy
#     X1   X0
#Q1 0.50 0.50
#Q2 0.75 0.25
#Q3 0.50 0.50
```

*NB, inspired from @akrun's idea of `ColMeans`:* You can also use `colMeans` instead of dividing `colSums`by the number of row to define X1:

```
X1 <- colMeans(dummy==1)
df_dummy <- data.frame(X1, X0=1-X1)
df_dummy
#     X1   X0
#Q1 0.50 0.50
#Q2 0.75 0.25
#Q3 0.50 0.50
```

Comment: Nevermind, it is bit of a hypocrisy when you are the one commented on my post and then tweaking my code and posting it in yours.

Answer (score 4):

We can try `apply` with `margin =2` and divide the counts of each value with the total length in the column

```
t(apply(dummy, 2, function(x) table(x)/length(x)))

#     0    1
#Q1 0.50 0.50
#Q2 0.25 0.75
#Q3 0.50 0.50
```

Comment: Thanks, but if one question had all 0s, then your answer doesn't work. i.e `dummy <- data.frame(Q1 = c(0, 0, 0, 0),
                    Q2 = c(1, 1, 0, 1),
                    Q3 = c(0, 1, 1, 0))`

Comment: @Adrian It does actually but in a different way. Try `apply(dummy, 2, function(x) table(x)/length(x))`

Answer (score 2):

We can do this with `table` and `prop.table`

```
t(sapply(dummy, function(x) prop.table(table(x))))
#     0    1
#Q1 0.50 0.50
#Q2 0.25 0.75
#Q3 0.50 0.50
```

---

Or a more efficient approach is to call `table` once

```
prop.table(table(stack(dummy)[2:1]),1)
#   values
#ind     0    1
#  Q1 0.50 0.50
#  Q2 0.25 0.75
#  Q3 0.50 0.50
```

---

Or another option is `colMeans` (inspired from @Cath's use of `colSums`)

```
X0 <- colMeans(!dummy)
data.frame(X1 = 1 - X0, X0)
#    X1   X0
#Q1 0.50 0.50
#Q2 0.75 0.25
#Q3 0.50 0.50
```

Comment: else I guess you could have gone with `as.logical`

Comment: you know you could just comment under other people's answer instead of making it yours (in one way or another), like commenting under mine "hey, you can also use colSums, turning 0/1 to logical" - which I thought of doing but decided for the other option, and under Ronak's "hey you can also call table only once"... That's actually what you are supposed to do...

Answer (score 2):

Another way to do this would be using do.call & lapply

```
do.call(cbind,lapply(dummy,function(x) data.frame(table(x))[,2]))
#    Q1 Q2 Q3
[1,]  2  1  2
[2,]  2  3  2
```

Comment: Not exactly the expected output OP is looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Less elegantly than in the answer above:

```
d <- t(dummy)
cbind(X0 = (ncol(d) - rowSums(d)) / ncol(d), X1 = rowSums(d) / ncol(d))
```

Or, to avoid computing the same stuff twice, and to get a data frame:

```
d <- t(dummy)
i <- ncol(d)
j <- rowSums(d)
data.frame(Question = rownames(d), X0 = (i - j) / i, X1 = j / i)
```

There you go:

```
   Question   X0   X1
Q1       Q1 0.50 0.50
Q2       Q2 0.25 0.75
Q3       Q3 0.50 0.50
```

Answer (score 1):

A tidyverse option:

```r
library(tidyr)
library(janitor)

dummy %>%
  gather(question, val) %>%    # reshape to long form
  tabyl(question, val) %>%    # make crosstab table
  adorn_percentages("row") %>%
  clean_names() 



 question   x0   x1
       Q1 0.50 0.50
       Q2 0.25 0.75
       Q3 0.50 0.50
```